# How can I include a strong name assembly file in my installer

Tags: wix, wix3.5, custom-action, strongname

I have a custom action to execute a custom action DLL but it is failing and I believe it's because it does not know how to read the strong name assembly

so I have this:

```
  <Binary Id="StrongName" SourceFile="$(var.MyProject.TargetDir)MyProject.CA.dll"/>

  <CustomAction Id="CreateIt"
                BinaryKey="StrongName"
                DllEntry="Create"
                Execute="deferred"
                Return="check"
                HideTarget="no"
                Impersonate="no" />

  <CustomAction Id="RemoveIt"
                BinaryKey="StrongName"
                DllEntry="Remove"
                Execute="deferred"
                Return="check"
                HideTarget="no"
                Impersonate="no" />

     <InstallExecuteSequence>
          <Custom Action="CreateIt" Before="InstallFinalize">(NOT REMOVE =       "ALL")</Custom>
          <Custom Action="RemoveIt" Before='InstallFinalize'>(NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")</Custom>
     </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

So how do I reference the signature as I execute this DLL?

Comment: By the way, the only error I have is. The wizard ended prematurely because of an error.  I have no more detail past this and do not know how to get more detail

Comment: If you enable Windows Installer Logging you should get all kinds of error detail including a .net stack dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was a security issue caused by an obsolete library which is not supported in .NET 4 and it is a different topic so I will not go into detail on it unless someone is curious.

Answer (score 1):

I assume from the *.CA.DLL nomenclature that you are using that this is a DTF custom action.  This is a native encapsulated DLL that hosts your managed DLL.  Being native, it can't be strong named.

Log the install and look through the log for the reason it is failing.